# Uniform and absolute convergence of a power series

Tags: analysis, power-series

I want to discuss the convergence of the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n \sqrt{n+1}}$ over $|z|≤ 1$. Now I have shown using ratio test that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = |z|≤ 1 $. Now how do I discuss the convergence of this series?

I understand that this series is unif. and abs. convergent for $|z|≤ R$ any $R<1$.

Thank you.

Comment: By M-test it is uniformly convergent for $|z|\le 1$.

Comment: Formatting tip: Use dollar signs (\$) to enclose math expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For each $z$ such that $|z|\leqslant1$,$$\left|\frac{z^n}{n \sqrt{n+1}}\right|\leqslant\frac1{n\sqrt{n+1}}.$$Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n \sqrt{n+1}}$ converges, your series converges uniformly and absolutely on $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid |z|\leqslant1\}$, by the Weierstrass $M$-test.